# How to fix error of No definition found for table?

Tags: php, facebook, yql

Does anyone know why I am getting the below error message? I am starting to learn the world of Facebook development and I cannot find a simple answer.

Code:

```
$twitterUrl ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
$twitterUrl .= urlencode("select * from twitter.status where id='jzm'");
$twitterUrl .="&format=json";

$twitterFeed = file_get_contents($twitterUrl, true);
$twitterFeed = json_decode($twitterFeed);

print_r($twitterFeed);
```

Error received:

```
stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [lang] => en-US [description] => No definition found for Table twitter.status ) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env` to your query.

```
   $twitterUrl ="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=";
    $twitterUrl .= urlencode("SELECT * FROM twitter.status WHERE id='jzm'");
    $twitterUrl .="&format=json";
    $twitterUrl .="&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env";

    $twitterFeed = file_get_contents($twitterUrl, true);
    $twitterFeed = json_decode($twitterFeed);

    print_r($twitterFeed);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you're trying to load the open table which Yahoo API doesn't recognise by default.

So you may prefix your query by the following query:

```
USE 'http://www.datatables.org/twitter/twitter.status.xml' AS twitter.status;
```

This will load the [custom community table](http://www.datatables.org/), so after that you can use it.

The general syntax is:

```
USE "http://myserver.com/mytables.xml" AS mytable;
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE...
```

Read more: [Invoking an Open Data Table Definition within YQL](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/yql-opentables-import.html)